# Rails bundler error installing Nokogiri (1.5.5) and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rails

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue

How to fix and get past the error?

```
Installing nokogiri (1.5.5) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

Comment: Have you installed libxslt package? If not try installing libxslt1.1 or libxslt1-dev

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
```

Comment: This worked for me too but for this error: libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.